# How to write Decrypt method with X509 certificate

Tags: c#, encryption, x509certificate2, encryption-asymmetric

I am new to development. I wrote a encrypt method with `X509` certificate. Now I want to write a decrypt method. I tried. but not working. Please help me to develop the decrypt method  Thank you.

Encrypt method(working correctly):

```
 private static string Encrypt(X509Certificate2 x509, string stringToEncrypt)
        {
            if (x509 == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToEncrypt))
                throw new Exception("A x509 certificate and string for encryption must be provided");

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509.PublicKey.Key;
            byte[] bytestoEncrypt = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
            byte[] encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(bytestoEncrypt, false);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
        }
```

Decrypt method that I tried:

```
private static string Decrypt(X509Certificate2 x509, string stringToDecrypt)
        {
            if (x509 == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToDecrypt))
                throw new Exception("A x509 certificate and string for encryption must be provided");

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509.PrivateKey; //when i use primaryKey here rsa always null
            // byte[] bytestoEncrypt = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToDecrypt);
            byte[] bytestoDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecrypt);
            byte[] encryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(bytestoDecrypt, false);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
        }
```

I don't have much knowledge about encryption and decryption. please help me to fix this.

Comment: The encryption is *not* working correctly. `ASCIIEncoding` is the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage that can't even handle all English words. Use `Encoding.UTF8` instead. .NET strings are Unicode, same as JavaScript, Python, Java etc. `Decrypt` will return the decrypted bytes that then need to be decoded using the same encoding that was used to convert the string to bytes. Once again, use`Encoding.UTF8`

Comment: ok, if u can provide the decrypt method as an answer, it will be more helpful to me.@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: You should not be converting the decrypted bytes to BASE64, you should be using `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()`. But yeah, you should really be using UTF-8 instead of ASCII.

Comment: if u can provide the decrypt method as an answer, it will be more helpful to me @phuzi

Answer (score 0):

The rules for decrypt are easy.  Starting from the last line of your encryption method, undo everything.

But, first, some notes.

- Don't use cert.PublicKey.Key.  It's `[Obsolete]` in newer versions of .NET.  Use `cert.GetRSAPublicKey()` (assuming it's RSA).

  - Similar with cert.PrivateKey
- Don't use RSACryptoServiceProvider.  It's old and crusty.  Just use the new, shiny, methods on the RSA base class.
- Encryption doesn't do text.  It does bytes.
- Repeat: Encryption doesn't do text.  It does bytes.
- RSA isn't for general data.  It's for relatively small messages, like an AES encryption key.

Here's the right way, which does AES encryption of the data, encrypts that key for the target certificate, and puts the two parts together.

```
private static byte[] Encrypt(X509Certificate2 targetCert, byte[] data)
{
    ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(data);
    EnvelopedCms cms = new EnvelopedCms(contentInfo);
    CmsRecipient recipient = new CmsRecipient(SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, targetCert);
    cms.Encrypt(recipient);

    return cms.Encode();
}

private static byte[] Decrypt(X509Certificate2 recipientCert, byte[] encrypted)
{
    EnvelopedCms cms = new EnvelopedCms();
    cms.Decode(encrypted);
    cms.Decrypt(new X509Certificate2Collection(recipientCert));
    return cms.ContentInfo.Content;
}
```

But that's no fun, so I guess we'll do it with the lower level types.

```
private static byte[] Encrypt(X509Certificate2 targetCert, byte[] data)
{
    using (RSA key = targetCert.GetRSAPublicKey())
    {
        return key.Encrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
    }
}

private static byte[] Decrypt(X509Certificate2 recipientCert, byte[] encrypted)
{
    using (RSA key = recipientCert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
    {
        return key.Decrypt(encrypted, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
    }
}
```

Oh, but you wanted strings.  Well, strings aren't bytes.  But they could be, if you encoded them.

```
private static byte[] EncryptString(X509Certificate2 targetCert, string message, Encoding encoding = null)
{
    return Encrypt(targetCert, (encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8).GetBytes(message));
}

private static byte[] DecryptString(X509Certificate2 targetCert, string message, Encoding encoding = null)
{
    return Decrypt(targetCert, (encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8).GetBytes(message));
}
```

Wrapping those in Base64 is an exercise left to the reader.